# What type of disease is my rose suffering from?

Tags: diseases

Can anyone help me identify what disease is infecting my rose canes as shown in the attached photos?

Thank you

Janice
[image]
[image]

Comment: This could be cankers. Elsewhere on the plant are these brown areas developing black spots?